Changing error type of ApplicativeError/MonadError
I use a library that produces a result with some custom error type. This library defines MonadError for that result type. For compatibility with the rest of my application, I'm trying to get ApplicativeThrow or MonadThrow out of that (i.e. change the error type).
I'd like to have something like this:
def changeErrorType[F[_], A, E1, E2](x: F[A])
        (convError: E1 => E2)
        (implicit ae1: MonadError[F, E1], ae2: MonadError[F, E2]): F[A] =
  x.attempt.flatMap(_.leftMap(convError).liftTo[F])

My understanding that this approach won't work because I cannot have 2 separate MonadError typeclasses for the same F but with different E1 and E2. So the signature could probably be:
def changeErrorType[F[_], G[_], A, E1, E2](x: F[A])
        (convError: E1 => E2)
        (implicit ae1: MonadError[F, E1], ae2: MonadError[G, E2]): G[A]

But I have no idea how to implement this.
Is there an idiomatic way to tackle this problem?
Update:
I can actually convert the library result to Either, then map their custom error to a Throwable, and lift Either into ApplicativeThrow. But I am wondering if the MonadError[*,CustomErrorType] instance that this library provides can be of any use if the rest of my code uses ApplicativeThrow/MonadThrow.

I believe what you want to do is simply not supported OOTB with Cats - there are bifunctor type class instances like Izumi BIO. Some people shove Eithers or EitherTs in type signatures. Others promote "classy optics" (basically make a sealed hierarchy extending Exception and handle everything with MonadThrow + Prism on Exception to handle/match/recreate errors). Some use all of the above as an argument for going ZIO. I guess for F[A] -> G[A] you'd be suggested to make a natural transformation F ~> G and pass it down from where types are known.

Does that custom type can hold Throwables? Does it provide some kind of leftMap or you don't know anything about it other than it is an F for which there is a MonadError instance using a non-throwable type?

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, no, that custom type cannot hold Throwables. The error is just a data structure describing an error.

Then there is nothing you can do. You need to transform that type into a valid F[_] : MonadThrow
